# Possible case of objects in infinitiv clauses

Tags: grammar-identification

Simply to check if my understanding is correct, in an infinitiv clause (constructed with zu), only objects can be there and no subjects. And, the objects are those required by the verb.

Is this correct? Or are there counter examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Infinitive clauses do not feature a subject. It's "borrowed" from the main clause.

> **Ich** erinnere mich daran, dass **ich** ihn kenne.
>
> **Ich** erinnere mich daran, ihn zu kennen.

If the subject of the object clause and the main clause aren't identical, you have to introduce an adverbial in the main clause you can "borrow" it from:

> Er erwartet (von mir), dass **ich** ihn treffe.
>
> Er erwartet **von mir**, ihn zu treffen.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically correct. Objects can be those required by the verb or optional with the verb, and there can of course also be other parts like adverbs and prepositionals, just no separate subject.

> Sie hofft, ihre Prüfung für den Führerschein dieses Jahr schon nach möglichst wenig Fahrstunden und gleich beim ersten Mal erfolgreich zu bestehen.